# How can i import external css in angular 7

Tags: angular7

How can i import bootstrap.css,jquery and JavaScript in my angular components and how can convert html webpage to angular webpage

Style.css
// Globally declaration for styles

@import url("./assets/css/bootstrap.css");

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can install bootstrap using npm.

```
npm install bootstrap --save
```

and then set the path in angular.json file as

```
"styles": [
      "src/styles.css",
       "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css",
 ]
```

This will do the work.